# Backbone: How to dispose a view/model when navigating to a route?

Tags: view, backbone.js

I am creating a webapp where user creates an inventory of items and he uses folders to categorize them. Now suppose I have two folders like this:

- All items (route: /)
- Closet items (route: #get/closet/id)

When I navigate between these routes, I want to dispose of the models rendered in the previous route. How and where should I do that? Is there an event which is triggered when I navigate to a new route where may be I can perform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to approach this, and it really depends on how you're doing the navigation. If you're changing routes with actual links, or by using `router.navigate()`, your `router` will dispatch a `route:<route name>` event that you can listen to, passing the same arguments to the handler as it passes to the route function.

In what turned out to be a demonstration of just how long it takes to set up test case code with Backbone, I made you a jsFiddle to illustrate this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/ZrgJF/7/

A lot of this is just setup code; the important parts for this question are the router:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'view/:id' : 'openView'
    },
    openView: function(id) {
        app.openView(id)
    }
});
router = new MyRouter();
```

And the view, which binds removal to the route:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(opts) {
        this.id = opts.id;
        router.bind('route:openView', this.dispose, this); 
    },
    // id is the same as the route argument
    dispose: function(id) {
        if (id != this.id) {
            this.remove();
        }
    }
    // etc
});
```